# Delphi Firemonkey TBannerAd "Message must be shown in the main UI thread" exception

Tags: delphi, admob, firemonkey

I created a mobile Android application in Delphi 10 Berlin and add TBannerAd at the bottom, according all instructions from Embarcodero website. Set up TBannerAd in test mode and start application on real device. TBAnnerAd showed nothing. On
OnDidFail events it is raised exception "Message must be shown in the  main UI thread"
  So, to make sure that it is not my code to blame I created empty application with only TBanneAd on it, but result is the same. What else I should check to find the reason?

Comment: Did you follow the example given in the documentation, [FMX.Advertising.TBannerAd](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FMX.Advertising.TBannerAd_(Delphi))?

Comment: Yes, I did all, from this instruction

Comment: Please edit the question and paste the code of your test application. It will be specially useful to see your `OnDidFail` code. Also include the exact error message passed to `OnDidFail`. Maybe the event is called from a secondary thread, you are doing something in the event handler that needs to be do in the UI thread and this is misleading you.

Comment: Thank you, JRL, you was right. I replaced OnDidFail event from ShowMessage(Error) to  CallInUiThread (
      procedure
      begin
        TJToast.JavaClass.makeText (SharedActivityContext,
            StrToJCharSequence(Msg), ToastLength).show
      end;   and now   OnDidFail event is showing error message:          "Ad failed to load: 2"

Comment: According to Google documentation  "Ad failed to load: 2" is internet connection problem error, but in reality the reason was wrong date and time on my mobile device. I correct date and everything works fine